# Unit Tests vs. Acceptance Tests

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, acceptance-testing

Are you for one or the other?  Or both?

My understanding is unit tests:

- validate the system from the developer's point of view
- help developers practice TDD
- keep code modular
- assist in detecting errors at low levels of granularity

Acceptance tests:

- validate the system from the business and QC / QA points of view
- tend to be high level as they're often written by people not familiar with the inner workings of the code

I feel both are necessary.  However, for minimization of redundant work, is it a good idea to try to incorporate unit tests into acceptance tests?  In other words, have the latter call the former.  Does going in the opposite direction make any sense?

What are your thoughts in general on unit tests vs. acceptance tests, and how to manage them in relation to each other?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Acceptance and integration tests tell you whether your code is working and complete; unit tests tell you where it's failing.

If you've done a good job with acceptance and integration tests, and they're passing, your code is implementing all the functionality it's supposed to, and it's working.  That's great to know (it's also great to know that it isn't).  But if it isn't working, an acceptance test won't give you much insight into what has gone wrong; since it tests many units of functionality, it can be kind of a bird's-eye view of failure.  This is where unit tests shine.  Good unit tests tell you exactly what went wrong, with exactly what part of your code.  It's harder to know whether you've written enough unit tests than acceptance tests, but when you have a failing acceptance test without a corresponding failing unit test - it's time to write that unit test.

That is all from the testing perspective.  And, of course, TDD isn't (and ATDD isn't) about testing.  With respect to driving your design, acceptance tests give you a broad roadmap ("here's where you want to go") while unit tests take you to the next intersection ("turn left").  They're both valuable in this regard and, again, their value complement one another.

Don't confuse them; don't miscegenate them.  Unit tests, in particular, shouldn't depend on anything else, and it would be a mistake to constrain your unit tests by making acceptance test dependent on them.  Of course they can share some framework code, but they should be independent.

Comment: Thanks, Carl.  Can you please talk a bit more about why we shouldn't constrain unit tests by tying acceptance tests to them?

Comment: Well, if an AT uses a UT, then we are less free to change the UT when we see that a better design is appropriate.  Every use of code constrains it and code (even tests) that is too tightly constrained becomes fragile.  UTs should be very malleable so we can restructure them to accommodate new requirements and visions.

Comment: You're describing an acceptance test as a piece of software being run and delivering the outcome. That's not at all what the term means to me.

Comment: Miscegenate? So, don't "racially mix up" Unit and Acceptance tests... I had to look that one up :-)

Answer (score 22):

As a summary of all the above,

- **Acceptance tests** make sure that you're building the **right thing**
- **Unit tests** make sure that you're building the **thing, right**

Answer (score 15):

> However, for minimization of redundant work, is it a good idea to try to incorporate unit tests into acceptance tests?

No.

> In other words, have the latter [acceptance] call the former [unit]. Does going in the opposite direction make any sense?

Don't bother.

Acceptance tests are often political.  You show them to people who -- based on their gut instinct -- decide to accept or reject.

Then you argue about the validity of the acceptance tests.

Then you argue about the scope of work and the next release.

Acceptance tests aren't -- generally -- technical.  If they were, then you'd have formal unit tests and that would be that.

Don't try to finesse the politics.  Embrace it.  Let it happen.

---

You can hope that Acceptance Test-Driven Development (ATDD) leads to "acceptance tests are written and agreed upon by the entire team before development begins."  But you have to reflect the reality that anything written in advance is specious at best and negotiable at worst.

The premise behind all Agile methods is that you can only agree to get to something releasable.  Everything after that is negotiable.

The premise behind all test-first (TDD, ATDD, or anything else) is that a test is an iron-clad agreement.  Except it's not.  With any TDD (or ATDD) method  you can agree -- in principle -- to the test *results*, but you haven't really agreed to the test *itself*.

It may arise that the test cannot easily be written.  Or worse, cannot be written at all.  You may agree to results that *seem* testable, but turn out to be poorly-defined.  What now?  These are things you can't know until you start development and get to details.

All testing is important.  And no particular kind of testing can be a superset or subset of any other kind testing.  They're always partially overlapping sets.  Trying to  combine to somehow save some work is likely to turn out to be a waste of time.

More testing is better than anything else.  The union of all tests has more value than trying to force a subset-superset relationship among tests.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  In ATDD, acceptance tests are written early, clearly and specifically though, right?  That is, they're not used to accept or reject any delivered functionality, but rather to specify what functionality should be delivered.  Developers know their code must pass acceptance tests before they can consider it done.

Comment: @Calvin: There's an inherent ambiguity here between "Acceptance" testing and any other testing you do.  All tests accept or reject functionality.  All tests.  If the test fails, it rejects functionality.  If the test passes, it accepts functionality.

Comment: I should've clarified.  I mean acceptance tests from the perspective of Acceptance Test-Driven Development (ATDD).  The doctrine of which is that acceptance tests are written and agreed upon by the entire team before development begins.  Developers then code with the awareness that their end goal is to make all acceptance tests pass (i.e., to meet all previously defined requirements).

Comment: @Calvin: "ATDD" has no practical difference from TDD which has no different from unit testing as a practice.  The one small difference is that "Acceptance" tests are more visible to users.  But there's no "inclusiveness" to one or the other.  They're just more tests. Tests are tests.  Since visibility is the only difference, don't over think it.

Comment: Thanks for the additional thoughts you added yesterday, S.

Comment: @S.Lott All to often as developers progress, testing always seems to be an issue. When a developer is introduced to testing after they've already become accustomed to their workflow, they have a very difficult time making that leap. I believe it's in part due to the confusion of different names, synonyms, and the lack of anyone giving a simple short, plain 'ole english explanation... Until now! You good sir have mastered the english language at a level above many, and have used it so very eloquently. For this, you have my deepest admiration.

Answer (score 14):

Unit Tests - my specific function does what it's supposed to do, nothing more, and nothing less.

Acceptance Test - my application does what it's supposed to do.

Example: Application to calculate roots of quadratic functions. Takes inputs of a, b, and c, returns roots x1 and x2. This application is built by functions I write to add two numbers, subtract two numbers, multiply two numbers, divide two numbers, and take the square root of two numbers.

Unit tests - check that my divide and multiply functions work correctly, my square root works correctly, my add and subtract work correctly.

Acceptance tests - check that my application calculates roots of quadratic functions.

Since my entire application is to calculate roots, I should not have a unit test that also calculates roots because there is no individual function which does so.

Answer (score 2):

These are just my personal opinion on the issue of some kinds of tests:

> However, for minimization of redundant
>   work, is it a good idea to try to
>   incorporate unit tests into acceptance
>   tests?

I'd second S. Lott's no on this and add that there is a danger here of the unit tests being rigged to some extent that may have some bugs pass through.  For example, on a drop down someone may test a few states but likely not all of them, where a tester may use different data to uncover a potential bug.

> In other words, have the latter call
>   the former. Does going in the opposite
>   direction make any sense?

I'd be careful of ever coupling them together.  The unit tests represent tests of the smallest bits of functionality, often so small that an end-user wouldn't understand that there may be hundreds of tests just to get a web form to enter data into a CRM system.  Acceptance tests are more about what the user of the application wants which can be more subjective,e.g. "Does this look pretty?" versus "Does this look right?"  There can be that mark of "good enough" with acceptance tests that I'm not sure would work with unit tests.  Generally if a unit test fails, then someone has to decide either to fix the code or remove the test as each can be a good option depending on circumstance.

> What are your thoughts in general on
>   unit tests vs. acceptance tests, and
>   how to manage them in relation to each
>   other?

Unit tests are about verifying the simplest pieces of code.  There can be integration tests but this is a level higher as once all the little pieces are checked, do the combination of the pieces work together,e.g. there were Saturday morning cartoons I watched growing up that had toys one could put together like "Voltron" or various Transformers like the Constructicons that formed Devastator.  Acceptance tests are generally from an end user perspective of, "Can I do X with the application now?" having an answer of "Yes," before something goes out the door.  While some error cases may be checked in an acceptance test, it isn't common to do a thorough test of every possible combination that one could enter into an application.  However, unit tests may cover boundary conditions and a few other random-like cases.